# Get every m2m relation in model as different object in DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model Jurisdiction that has M2M relation with Franchise. And I use ModelViewSet on Jurisdiction.
**models.py**

```
class Franchise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255, db_index=True)


class Jurisdiction(models.Model):
    franchise = models.ManyToManyField(
        Franchise,
        verbose_name='Franchise',
        related_name='jurisdictions',
        blank=True
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        "Jurisdiction name",
        max_length=255,
        db_index=True,
        unique=True,
    )
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        "Phone number",
        max_length=12,
        validators=[phone_number_regex],
        unique=True,
    )
```

**My views.py**

```
class JurisdictionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Jurisdiction.objects.all().prefetch_related('franchise')
    serializer_class = JurisdictionSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class JurisdictionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    franchise = FranchiseSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Jurisdiction
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'phone_number', 'franchise',
        )
```

And serializer shows me:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test juris 1",
  "phone_number": "200-000-1233",
   "franchise": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test franchise 1",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test franchise 2",
      }
}
```

How I can get a list view of every m2m relation as a different object in serializer? I tried to change the **to_representation** method of serializer but nothing works
**expected output:**

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test juris 1",
      "phone_number": "200-000-1233",
      "franchise_name": "Test franchise 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test juris 1",
      "phone_number": "200-000-1233",
      "franchise_name": "Test franchise 2"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [customize the `ListSerializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior) of your `ModelSerializer`. Specifically the [`to_representation` method](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.serializers/ListSerializer.html#to_representation). For example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class CustomJurisdictionListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data

        response = []
        
        for item in iterable:
            item_representation = self.child.to_representation(item)
            for franchise in item.franchise.all():
                representation = item_representation.copy()
                representation['franchise_name'] = franchise.name
                response.append(representation)
                
        return response
```

Then remove `franchise` from `JurisdictionSerializer` and set the custom list serializer:

```
class JurisdictionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Jurisdiction
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'phone_number',
        )
        list_serializer_class = CustomJurisdictionListSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Do you know how to order by this additional field?

Comment: Do you want to order it by a field in `Jurisdiction` or in `Franchise`?